# Downcasting to generic type

Tags: c#

I have the following classes:

```
public interface IFile { }

public class File : IFile { }

public class FTPFile : File { }

public interface IFileManager<T> where T : IFile
{
    void SaveFile(T file);
}

internal class FTPFileManager : IFileManager<FTPFile>
{
    public void SaveFile(FTPFile file) { }
}
```

I have multiple file types and managers defined in my project but I tried to keep it simple. In my factory class, I have a method like the following where it can't cast `FTPFileManager` to `IFileManager<IFile>` but interestingly it can cast `FTPFileManager` to `IFileManager<FTPFile>`. In both cases there  is no compile error but in runtime it throws error.

```
public class FileManagerFactory
{
    public static IFileManager<IFile> GetFileManager(IFile file)
    {
        if (file is FTPFile)
            return (IFileManager<IFile>)new FTPFileManager(); //No compile error but in runtime it throws casting error
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't. If it was allowed, then you could call `SaveFile` with another implementation of `IFile` but your `FTPFileManager` needs `FTPFile`

Comment: `FTPFileManager` isn't an `IFileManager<IFile>` since it cannot save instances of `IFile`, only `FTPFile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go about this is to use the following pattern:

```
public interface IFile { }

public class FTPFile : IFile { }

public interface IFileManager
{
    void SaveFile(IFile file);

    bool Accepts(IFile file);
}

public abstract class FileManager<TFile>
    : IFileManager
    where TFile : IFile
{
    protected abstract void SaveFile(TFile file);

    public void SaveFile(IFile file)
    {
        var cast = (TFile)file; // will throw a compile exception if wrong one

        this.SaveFile(cast);
    }

    public bool Accepts(IFile file)
    {
        return file is TFile;
    }
}

internal class FTPFileManager : FileManager<FTPFile>
{
    protected sealed override void SaveFile(FTPFile file)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Saved file");
    }
}

public static IFileManager GetFileManager(IFile file)
{
    var managers = new List<IFileManager> { new FTPFileManager() };

    return managers.Single(manager => manager.Accepts(file));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You would be able to cast `FTPFileManager` to `IFileManager<IFile>` if `IFileManager` were covariant, i.e. declared as:

```
public interface IFileManager<out T> where T : IFile
```

However, this won't compile because `IFileManager` has `T` as an *input* parameter to one of its methods. For an interface to be covariant in `T`, it must have `T` only as a type of *return* parameters.

This makes sense in your situation, because `FTPFileManager` needs to be given an instance of `FTPFile`. If you could write:

```
var ftpManager = new FtpFileManager();
IFileManager<IFile> fileManager = ftpManager;
fileManager.SaveFile(new SomeOtherFileType());
```

Then the FTP file manager would be expecting an `FTPFile` but instead be passed something else. For that reason, the second line refuses to compile.

---

Note that this also highlights a risk downcasting (or, at least, downcasting without being very clear on why you're doing it). By writing:

```
return (IFileManager<IFile>)new FTPFileManager();
```

instead of

```
return new FTPFileManager();
```

you turned a compile-time error into a runtime one.

Comment: Then how should I implement my factory method so that it can properly decide which file manager to use? I shouldn't return IFileManager<IFile> I guess?

Comment: @sotn Yeah unfortunately this is a difficult situation. One way is to never lose the information of which type of file you're holding- instead of an `IFile`, always hold a `TFile`, making all the methods that pass it around generic. Then `GetFileManager` can be a generic method. This is sometimes impractical. Another way would be for the `FileManagers` to not be generic but all downcast. This is hacky and loses you a lot of compile-time safety.

Answer (score 0):

```
 internal class FTPFileManager : IFileManager<IFile>
    {
        public void SaveFile(IFile file) { }
    }
public class FileManagerFactory
    {
        public static IFileManager<IFile> GetFileManager(IFile file)
        {
            if (file is FTPFile)
                return new FTPFileManager();                 
        }
    }
```

Try above. It will work.

Comment: It will, but requires `FTPFileMananger.SaveFile` not to make use of any members on `FTPFile` which aren't on `IFile`

Comment: Could you elaborate more. Thanks

Comment: Well, say `FTPFile` has a member called `Url` which isn't on `IFile`, but which is required to save. Then `FTPFileManager` wouldn't work, unless it casts `file` to `FTPFile`.

Comment: Agree. I suggested considering interface is returned and meant to consume interface members only. If genrics are being used it is meant to be type safe. And if casting is required then I treat it as design issue.